# How to filter a view item by Publishing date?

Tags: 2013, list-view, publishing-page, publishing

I'm currently working on a custom view, which has to show the 5 latest news modified in SP.
My filters are on the content type, and on the type of news. My library is a page Library. Everything worked fine. Until my customer asked me to add planning options.

So now, I would like my view to filter the item by :

- `Planification Start Date` - which has to be inferior or equal to [Today]
- `Planification End Date` - which has to be superior or equal to [Today]

So, I filled the filters. But nothing shows up.

I've checked my items and when somebody Choose "NOW" in the planning options, nothing appear in the `Planification Start Date` Column.

So the question is :

HOW can I filter my items by `Planification Start Date` and `End date`? When the column is not filled?

Comment: Do you want to display rows which has empty date values along with the above condition?

Comment: @AmalHashim I did not express myself right. let me clear it : When somebody publish a page and set `planification start date` to "NOW", the planification start date is empty. But the page has to be visible for people, so i would like to include it in the view, yes.

Comment: What is the data type of field `planification start date`?

Comment: these are automatic columns created by SP2013 when activating Plan. The data type i can see is "Start Date of publications' plan" and "End Date of publication's plan". Sorry if it is not so explicit, but my version of SP is in french..

Answer (score 0):

For filtering out blank dates you can add more conditions to the existing filter.

```
Planification Start Date "is not equal to" __ (Keep blank)
AND
Planification Start Date "is less than or equal to" [Today]
AND
Planification End Date "is not equal to" __ (Keep blank)
AND
Planification End Date "is greater than or equal to" [Today]
```

Comment: as i explained on your previous comment, the problem is that when user set "planification start date" to "now", sharepoint does not fill planification start date columns, but my page is set as "published and visible for everyone NOW", so i would like it to appear. Your additionnal filters won't give me that. Do you have any idea on how to achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: So instead of blank you can use `[Planification Start Date[ "is  equal to" NOW OR [Planification Start Date[ "is less than or equal to" [Today]`

Comment: there is no "NOW" nor [Now] possible filter. Only a [Today]. And, let me repeat, i think i'm not clear : when filling the start plan date with "NOW" (in a little form created by sharepoint), the start plan date column does contain nothing. It is empty, so i can't filter on it, but i need to do it. Do you have any idea, please?